# Loading react-dom fails with require

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Due to technical reasons I have to load react-dom with the require() method. However when I use `require('react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js')` I get an error: "Dc is undefined"

When I use react-dom.development.js the error is "_ReactInternals$Sched is undefined". How does that come? It works fine with require("react-dom") but I specifically want the production build

Comment: Are you including `react` first?

Comment: Yes i am. I have `window.React = require('react/umd/react.production.min.js');` right above it